# iPad Pencil touch triggers immediate screen movement instead of a click

Tags: ipad, web-browser, html, apple-pencil

On our new iPads using Pencil, whenever our users touch the browser window, the screen starts to scroll/move. But what we expect is that it triggers a click the same way as if you had used your finger.

The Pencils sensitivity is just to high, you have to be pretty fast and precise to get a click. That's totally annoying.

Is there a trick (maybe CSS) to have the screen movement on delay and not immediate?